# How to identify the surrounding rectangle

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, image-recognition

How to identify the approximate surrounding rectangle of the given dots?

Expected output: as shown by the upper part of the below image.

Input: the lower part.

[image]

Comment: There are many surrounding rectangles for any finite set of points. You need to tell which one you want. Minimal area? Minimal perimeter? Prettiest looking?

Comment: Build convex hull and then build rectangle in O(n) time complexity (where n is number of dots in convex hull).

Comment: @n.m. It's best to find the prettiest looking one. As a human, the first impression of the image results a square, though it is mathematically true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is do the follow two steps:

1. Find the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of the points
2. Find a minimum bounding box of a convex polygon can be solved in O(n), following by this [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box_algorithms)

**Edited**: Okay actually the above 2 steps is not enough to be a correct and accepted answer.

Before these 2 steps, you have to preprocess the set of point first.

1. Check if any 3 or more points are collinear, remove those points except the two end points.
2. After step 1, you should now get a set of points that have no 3 or more points are collinear.

check the size of set : if it has only 1 point or 2 points left, you have to special handle them (for 1 point you may just find any minimal box to contain it by your own method; for 2 points maybe make them become the bounding box's diagonal?)

If the resulting set has >= 3 points left, then just follow my original 2 steps: convex hull + rotating calipers

cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this is a [**minimzation problem with constraints**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_optimization).

You need to find 4 lines:

```
l1: a1x + b1y + c1 = 0
l2: a1x + b1y + c2 = 0
l3: a2x + b2y + c3 = 0
l4: a2x + b2y + c4 = 0
```

So, you have 8 variables: `a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2,c3,c4`

You need to **minimize**:

```
Sum(distance(li,point_j) | i from [1,4], j - over all points)
```

subject to constraints:

```
l1 dot l3 = 0  [ensuring rectangle - cosine=0->angle between lines=90]
for each point j:
a1xj + b1yj + c1 >=0 ['above' l1]
a1xj + b1yj + c2 <= 0 ['below' l2]
(similarly for l3,l4)
```

Note you can change target function to match other minimization criteria like minimum area.

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated.